# Internationalization in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

I am implementing Internalization in Spring MVC. Below is my applicationcontext xml file

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/ApplicationResources"></property>
</bean>
```

I have kept ApplicationResources_en.properties file under /Webcontent/WEB-INF/ directory.

In JSP, I m loading messages using `<fmt:message>` tag. But I m getting message as below.
???addEmployee.UserName???

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you registered a `LocaleChangeInterceptor` bean to intercept the user's Locale:

```
<mvc:interceptors>    
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
      p:paramName="locale" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Then try to use `<spring:message code="addEmployee.UserName" text="username" />` instead of  tag.

Otherwise, the `<spring:message>` closely resemebles to `<fmt:message>` except that the later does not use the Spring locale resolver and you have to change the resolver to

```
`<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>`
```

which will set a LocalizationContext for JSTL tags.

BR.

Comment: Can i not use <fmt:message> tag instead of <spring:message> ?
Is there any specific reason for using <spring:message> tag?

Comment: Actually yes you can use the `<fmt:message>` tag for sure but I haven't touch it for a while and as I can remember it won't work unless you specify a view resolver for your jsp files `<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>` which actually will set the LocalizationContext and do all the magic for you.

Comment: I had configured view to 'InternalResourceView'. Now i changed to 'JstlView'. Its working !!
Many thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome and I'm going to edit my answer so it is made available for developers that gets stack with the same problem (Feel free to up-vote it so it became a trusted answer :) ).